# Dynamic SQL INSERT VALUES SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Working on a project that requires a procedure with a dynamic table name. Need to work out how to write an insert value query into the table. Not a massive project so overheads and such is not an issue.

Tried several variations however it always falls over.

```
DECLARE @DynamicTableName NVARCHAR(100)
SET @DynamicTableName = 'DynamicTableName'


    INSERT @DynamicTableName
    (
        HolidayStartDate
      , HolidayEndDate
      , HolidayType
      , HolidayTypeID
      , StaffCode
      , StaffName
      , Notes
      , FTE
      , CreatedBy
      , CreatedDate
      , HolidayRequestID
    )
    VALUES
    (       @Para1,
            @Para2,
            @Para3,
            @Para4,
            @Para5,
            @Para5,
            @Para6,
            @Para7,  
            @Para8,
            @Para9, 
            @Para10
    )
```

Comment: Not gonna work, an object identifier may not be referenced via a variable.  Construct the SQL within a string and call `sp_executeSQL`, this supports input parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the Para1-n into a #Temp table and then perform a dynamic insert.

The benefit here is that you don't have parse or quote parameters

```
DECLARE @DynamicTableName NVARCHAR(100)
SET @DynamicTableName = 'DynamicTableName'

Select  P1=@Para1,P2=@Para2,P3=@Para3,P4=@Para4,P5=@Para5,P6=@Para6,P7=@Para7,P8=@Para8,P9=@Para9,P10=@Para10 Into TempInsert 
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Insert Into '+@DynamicTableName +'(
        HolidayStartDate
      , HolidayEndDate
      , HolidayType
      , HolidayTypeID
      , StaffCode
      , StaffName
      , Notes
      , FTE
      , CreatedBy
      , CreatedDate
      , HolidayRequestID
    ) Select * From #TempInsert'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**EDIT - I should note that I see only 10 parameters yet you have 11 fields.**

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100),@QueryStr NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @QueryStr = 'INSERT INTO ' +@TableName+ '(     
HolidayStartDate,HolidayEndDate,HolidayType, HolidayTypeID, StaffCode
, StaffName, Notes, FTE, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, HolidayRequestID)
VALUES ('+ @Para1 +','+ @Para2 +','+ @Para3 +','+ @Para4 +','+ @Para5 +','+  
@Para5 +','+ @Para6 +','+ @Para7 +','+ @Para8 +','+ @Para9 +','+ @Para10 +')'

 EXEC (@QueryStr)
```

Comment: sp_executeSQL is a better choice as it will escape text within the variables if they are treated as parameters, EXEC() can lead to injection vulnerabilities.